# How to store the current page in an iOS Cordova application?

Tags: cordova, storage

i want to know how can i store the current html page of my iOS Cordova app? I use html, css and js.

I have several html pages in my app and when the user leaves the application, I want that when it restarts it arrives on the same page.

I never use store data before in an app project.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a plugin like [cordova-plugin-nativestorage](https://github.com/TheCocoaProject/cordova-plugin-nativestorage) to store data persistent. If a users enters a page you save some `id` or `name` like this:

```
NativeStorage.setItem("currentPage",yourId, <success-callback>, <error-callback>);
```

When the user reopens the app you fetch this value:

```
NativeStorage.getItem("currentPage",<success-callback>, <error-callback>);
```

And redirect your user in the success-callback function to the page associated with this `id` or `name`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I do not know exactly where I can add these two lines of code...

Comment: Have a look at the example at their repository: https://github.com/TheCocoaProject/cordova-plugin-nativestorage/tree/master/examples/demo

Comment: Thanks for the link. My idea is to save the current page, but without any button. I think the bast way to start is with this file : https://github.com/TheCocoaProject/cordova-plugin-nativestorage/blob/master/examples/demo/www/js/index.js

Comment: Yes thats a good start. Cordovas lifecycle events could also be of use for you: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html